# How to use enum with spaces in java

Tags: java, selenium

I have an issue that I want to resolve.
I am using selenium and on of the tests I need to select values from dropdown.
the values are:

```
Unassigned - 1
Self Service -  2
```

I want to create enum with name opsOwner that will contains these values.
the problem with the values are the spaces.
How can I create enum with this values, and in other class assigned them?

this is my code:

```
public enum OpsOwner
{
    selfService ("Self Service - 2");
    unassigned("Unassigned - 1");

    private String opsOwnerValue;

    OpsOwner(String value)
    {
        this.opsOwnerValue = value;
    }

    OpsOwner(){}

    public String opsOwnerValueValue(){ return opsOwnerValue; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "opsOwnerValue{" +
                "opsOwnerValue='" + opsOwnerValue + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
}
```

and this is how I want to use the code:

```
PubOpsApproveExPublisherObject.OpsOwner.selfService;
```

the code is only worked if I removed the

```
unassigned("Unassigned - 1");
```

when I add the second value 
        unassigned("Unassigned - 1");
it says missing method body. I just want enum with values of spaces, and than evaluate it.
can someone please advise how can I use it?
for now I am not using enum but String since I need the flexibility.

Comment: Use commas to separate enum values & end with a semicolon only after the last enum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
 public enum OpsOwner {
        selfService("Self Service - 2"), // Comma here!
        unassigned("Unassigned - 1");

        private String opsOwnerValue;

        OpsOwner(String value) {
            this.opsOwnerValue = value;
        }

        OpsOwner() {}

        public String opsOwnerValueValue() { return opsOwnerValue; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "opsOwnerValue{" +
                    "opsOwnerValue='" + opsOwnerValue + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Comment: TNX IT WORKED ֱֱ

Answer (score 1):

Enum values should be separated by commas. You have declared them separated by semi-colon. Try the one below.

```
public enum OpsOwner
{
    selfService ("Self Service - 2"), unassigned("Unassigned - 1");

    private String opsOwnerValue;

    OpsOwner(String value)
    {
        this.opsOwnerValue = value;
    }

    OpsOwner(){}

    public String opsOwnerValueValue(){ return opsOwnerValue; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "opsOwnerValue{" +
                "opsOwnerValue='" + opsOwnerValue + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```